# PDFKit in iOS Annotation dictionary value for annotation frame returns NSRect

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdfkit

how does one take an the value of NSRect shown below and convert it to a CGRect?

```
{
    "/A" = (null);
    "/Border" = "PDFBorder: {solid lineWidth:1.0 hCorner:0.0 vCorner:0.0 dashCount:0 dashPattern:(\n)}";
    "/DA" = "/Helvetica-Bold 12 Tf 0 g";
    "/F" = 4;
    "/FT" = "/Btn";
    "/Ff" = 65536;
    "/MK" = "<PDFAppearanceCharacteristics: 0x600002702eb0>";
    "/Rect" = "NSRect: {{61.825100000000006, 230.45099999999999}, {212.82389999999998, 38.096000000000032}}";
    "/Subtype" = "/Widget";
    "/T" = "signature_af_image";
    "/Type" = "/Annot";
}
```

this is the value in question:

> "/Rect" = "NSRect: {{61.825100000000006, 230.45099999999999},
>   {212.82389999999998, 38.096000000000032}}";

I've tried casting this like so, and while this seems to work, the values inside the CGRect don't match the values inside the NSRect. They are of by a magnitude of 10^30

> CGRect *tempRect = (__bridge CGRect*)[annot.annotationKeyValues
>   objectForKey:PDFAnnotationKeyRect];

so casting doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

i'm an idiot, the answer is already in documentation with

> // Required for all annotations. The bounding box in page-space of the
>   annotation.

```
@property (nonatomic) PDFRect bounds;
```

oh well, this works